# Root for HTC desire U dual sim not found

Tags: rooting, root-access, htc

I bought a new HTC Desire U dual SIM phone but did not find even a single rooting method. How do I root this phone?

Comment: What is this tweak are you talking about?

Comment: You need to root your device (HTC desire)? Please state your question correctly.

Comment: I want to root my desire u dual sim to flash custom roms but could not find any.